NAV2 controller plugin asking directly for re-planning or recovery behavior to BT
In the actual Nav2 architecture, the requests for re-planning or for triggering a recovery behavior are performed by the progress checker plugin to the BT. There are, however, situations in witch one would like to have the controller plugin asking directly for a re-planning or for triggering a recovery behavior. A typical example is an optimization controller like MPC: if the optimization problem is infeasible (i.e., no cmd_vel can be determined) for N consecutive cycles the controller plugin should be able to ask for a re-planning or a recovery action.
Is there a "clean" way, compatible with the actual architecture, to implement this behavior?

Yes, have the controller plugin throw one of the Nav2 exception types. For Iron and newer, that will propogate up to the BT in the form of an error code that can be captured in the blackboard and used to process specific contextual actions.
You can see that capture in the Controller server here,  populating the error_code response field to the actions. The is then populated in the error_code_id output port for the node here.
See our BT XMLs provide for examples of how to populate those onto the blackboard and use in other BT nodes (example). We also have BT nodes that use these to make contextual actions like WouldAControllerRecoveryHelp.
